# Deploying Vue.js 3 application using Vuetify 3 and Vite (to nested folder)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I have created an app using Vue.js 3 and Vuetify 3, which uses Vite.  If I deploy to production in the root folder, it works fine (ie, if I access it from http://example.com).  But, I'm trying to deploy to a folder called "app" (ie. http://example.com/app).  The reason is that the root folder contains a marketing web site, and I don't want to overwrite that.

If it makes any difference, I am using TypeScript as well.

I've consulted the Vite documentation, and you can change the public path using:

vite build --base=/my/public/path/

In my case, I tried:

vite build --base=/app/

I've tried this, but it doesn't work when I deploy to Production in the "app" folder.  I see the title on the web page appear correctly, but the entire screen is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the base path in `vite.config.ts` instead:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  base: '/app/',
})
```

Furthermore you can also check the generated `index.html` to see if the relative file paths of files being included match correctly with what you would expect serving the application at `/app/`.

Comment: I tried that, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I use react/vite and in my case i done all things which you have done but i also make change baseurl of my Router component in App.js file.

```
<div className="App">
    <Router basename="/app/">
          //all routes
    </Router>
</div>
```